# Creating a page to show data with foreign keys

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm creating an APEX application that allows students to apply to job placements, and allows an admin to see all interactions. I want to create a page to show all of the students applications.

First off, here's the database schema for the tables involved:
[image]

Full sized link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QU1Pr.png

I have a report with a list of students and I've added a "View Applications" column. I've made the "View Applications" column linkable, and it goes to the new page. The problem is, I have no idea how to show all of the applications for the student that the admin is currently looking up.

The only way I can think of doing it is passing `RECORD_NUMBER` (PK in `students` table) to the new page and then executing some SQL using that, and populating the page fields with what's returned. But I have no idea how to do that. I don't know how to grab the `RECORD_NUMBER` value to use in SQL and I don't know how to populate form fields with what's returned by the SQL.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So you've got one page that lists applications and the students that have applied. We'll call that page 1. If I understand what you're trying to do, you can create a page 2, with a report and a hidden page item. Call the page item P2_RECORD_NUMBER.

Create the report with the query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl_jobs j
 INNER JOIN tbl_applications a on a.job_id = j.id
 INNER JOIN tbl_students s ON s.record_number = j.record_number
 WHERE s.record_number = :P2_RECORD_NUMBER
```

Now edit the link on page 1 so it points to page 2 and populates P2_RECORD_NUMBER with the record_number of the row that the user clicked on. I don't have Apex in front of me, but I think you can do that by editing the report attributes for that column. Also, you can use the url of the form `http://site.com/f?p=<APP_ID>:<PAGE_ID>:0::::P2_RECORD_NUMBER:<record_number>`. (I'm doing that from memory and may have the number of colons wrong.)

You'll also want to have some default text in place in case the query above returns no rows.

Comment: Very useful, thanks. I followed the steps and used `:P17_RECORD_NUMBER` in my query but it throws this error when I navigate to the page: `ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "P17_RECORD_NUMBER" in application "289".` Is it looking for a field on the page to put `P17_RECORD_NUMBER` into? Because there isn't one, I just want to use the record number in my query.

Comment: Did you add a hidden page item called P17_RECORD_NUMBER to page 17? You need a place to store the record number until Apex can run the query. This blog post says that can also happen if there is a space in the text box when you're making the link: http://oraclequirks.blogspot.com/2012/02/err-1002-unable-to-find-item-id-for.html

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new page for the admin and enter a query like

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl_students s
  JOIN tbl_applications a USING (record_number)
  JOIN tbl_jobs j ON a.job_id = j.id
```

Do you know where to add the query?

Comment: I don't, and I don't know how to get the record_number into the query (it's passed to the page using "Column Link") or populate form fields using the results of the query.

Comment: Do you want to display all applications or all applications of one particular student?

Comment: Oracle's 2 Day Guide has an example how to add or modify the query: [Modifying the Departments Report](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35122/build_app.htm#BCEBJJGB)

Comment: All applications of one particular student defined by record_number. Thanks, I'll take alook at the guide.